# How can I remove duplicate member from array of objects based on object property values?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

The array looks like:

```
var test = [
           {
            Time: new Date(1000), 
            psi:100.0
           }, 
           {
            Time: new Date(1000), 
            psi:200.0
           }, 
           {
            Time: new Date(2000), 
            psi:200.0
           }
          ]
```

The function looks like (the function was copied from some online resource, couldn't find the exact reference.)

```
function uniqTimetable(nums){
  console.log(nums); //log#1
  var length = nums.length;
  var count = 0;
  for (var i =0; i< length-1; i++){
    if (nums[count].Time.getTime() !== nums[i+1].Time.getTime()){
      count ++;
      nums[count] = nums[i+1];
    }
  }
  nums.length = count + 1;
  console.log(nums); // log #2
}

uniqTimetable(test);
console.log(test);// log #3
```

Are there any problems of

- copy one object to the other array member by this line`nums[count] = nums[i+1]`
- rescale the array length by this line`nums.length = count + 1`
  ?

With electron/node.js, the output looks a bit weird.

In log#1, it shows the array length is 2 instead of 3. Something seems wrong with the function. Any suggestions welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of `nodejs` are you using?

Comment: @PanwenWang 12.16.3

Comment: Wired though. Mine is older (`12.13.0`), but it shows correct about the length of `test`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the problem, you can solve it in one line function:

```js
const test = [{
    Time: new Date(1000),
    psi: 100.0
  },
  {
    Time: new Date(1000),
    psi: 200.0
  },
  {
    Time: new Date(2000),
    psi: 200.0
  }
]

const unique = test.filter(({Time}, i, array) => 
  !array.find((item, j) => item.Time.getTime() === Time.getTime() && j > i));

console.log(unique);
```

(I assumed `psi` is not relevant)

It uses [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) array's methods.

Comment: Love it, but i  work on a legacy team that would get confused by the chaining :D

Answer (score 1):

```js
function removeDuplicates(myArr, prop) {
    return myArr.filter((obj, pos, arr) => {
        return arr.map(mapObj => mapObj[prop]).indexOf(obj[prop]) === pos;
    });
}
removeDuplicates(test,"Time")
```

Using the filter function of javascript, to return the List of only unique elements.

Comment: Changed based on your comment @soumyasunny

Answer (score 1):

I like @Akin's answer! But unfortunately the `.indexOf()` function does not work for Date objects with the same value, since each object is still considered to be different and the `.indexOf()` function will always find the index of the Date object itself and never another "copy". To overcome this I convert the Date object back to milliseconds before collecting the values in an array (`tst`). I do this with `myArr.map(mapObj => mapObj[prop].getTime())` before I go into the `.filter` function.

As the `.getTime()` method will only work for Date objects it does not make sense to keep the property `prop` as an argument. Instead I hardcoded the `.Time` property into the code.

**Edit:**

By coercing a numerical data type with a unary operator `+` for the `.Time` property I can leave out the `.getTime()` method which will be applied implicitly.

```js
var test = [{Time: new Date(1000), psi:100.0}, 
            {Time: new Date(1000), psi:200.0}, 
            {Time: new Date(2000), psi:200.0}];

function Cars10m_remDups(myArr) {
  let tst=myArr.map(o=>+o.Time);
  return myArr.filter((o, i)=>tst.indexOf(+o.Time)===i);
}
// for comparison: --> will list all three objects!
function Akin_remDups(myArr, prop) {
  return myArr.filter((obj, pos, arr) => {
   return arr.map(mapObj => mapObj[prop]).indexOf(obj[prop]) === pos;
  });
}
// Zero's one-liner works too, here: my shortened version
const Zero_remDups = myArr => myArr.filter(({Time}, i, array) => 
  !array.find((item, j) => +item.Time-Time==0&&i>j));
// also: with "i>j" I pick the first unique (Zero chose the last)


console.log('Cars10m:',Cars10m_remDups(test));
console.log('Akin:',Akin_remDups(test,"Time"));
console.log('Zero:',Zero_remDups(test));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```